# Options menu dose not show in android 4.3

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add options menu, but for some reasons it does not show up in android 4.3, the options menu button is not even shown! 
Here is my codes:

My **activity** is:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
            return true;
        }

         ...
    }
```

My **menu** is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.meysam.timesheet.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

**androidManifest** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.meysam.timesheet">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

My Options menu dose not show in android 4.3, but correctly work in higher android versions.

What can i do?

Comment: Does your 4.3 device has physical menu button?(Samsung has it), Android will automatically hide the three dots. If you don't, it will show them.

Comment: just add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your onCreate() method

Comment: You probably need to call "super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)"